# update the value of a cell in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am trying to fill the values of a variable row by row for which I loop through the dataframe and when I have the value I want to fill I do this::

```
listadoProyectosPlanificados<-function(df){
variables<-names(df)
variablesAIgnorar<-c('Total','JefeProyecto','Ranking','Proyectos')
variablesATenerEncuenta<-subset(variables,!(variables %in% variablesAIgnorar))
for (indiceFila in 1:nrow(df)) {
 proyectos<-vector()
 for (indiceColumna in 1:length(variablesATenerEncuenta)) {
  if (df[indiceFila,variablesATenerEncuenta[indiceColumna]]!=0) {
    proyectos<-append(proyectos,variablesATenerEncuenta[indiceColumna])
  }
}
print(indiceFila)
print(ncol(df))
print(paste(proyectos,collapse = ', '))
df[indiceFila,ncol(df)]<-paste(proyectos,collapse = ', ')
}
}
```

[image: prints]

But this sentence do nothing in df

```
df[indiceFila,ncol(df)]<-paste(proyectos,collapse = ', ')
```

but if I do this in consle
    df[1,49]<-paste(c('hola','adios'),collapse = ', ')

```
> df[1,49]
[1] "hola, adios"
```

it updates

any idea, please?

regards

Comment: Changes made in functions stay inside functions. You should have your function `return()` the modified data frame, and then assign the result, e.g., `df <- listadoProyectosPlanificados(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `MyDataFrame` to the name of your data frame and it should work.

```
listadoProyectosPlanificados <- function(df){
  variables<-names(df)
  variablesAIgnorar<-c('Total','JefeProyecto','Ranking','Proyectos')
  variablesATenerEncuenta<-subset(variables,!(variables %in% variablesAIgnorar))
  for (indiceFila in 1:nrow(df)) {
    proyectos<-vector()
    for (indiceColumna in 1:length(variablesATenerEncuenta)) {
      if (df[indiceFila,variablesATenerEncuenta[indiceColumna]]!=0) {
        proyectos<-append(proyectos,variablesATenerEncuenta[indiceColumna])
      }
    }
    print(indiceFila)
    print(ncol(df))
    print(paste(proyectos,collapse = ', '))
    df[indiceFila,ncol(df)]<-paste(proyectos,collapse = ', ')
  }

  return( df ) #new statement
}

MyDataFrame <- listadoProyectosPlanificados(MyDataFrame)
```